# what data you can get from the web page

Tags: web

Please, what data you can get from the web page. I mean the data ip, on ip geolocation, visited pages. And what else can you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A website can get alot of information

by using the Javascript [Navigator](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp) object:

-codename of the browser(appCodeName)

-name of the browser(appName)

-version information of the browser(appVersion)

-geolocation(geolocation)

-if cookies are enabled(cookieEnabled)

-language(language)

-wether the browser is online(onLine)

-the platform(platform)

-engine of the browser(product)

-userAgent sent by the browser(userAgent)

and little things using the client and window objects:

-cursor position

-screensize

-wether javasript is enabled

and things like the ip adress by using the web server

(this is not everything)

Comment: Thanks! Can I get history of visited sites, the number of sites visited, information about e-mail from the web page?

Comment: There are some tricks @vasilek , for example, did you notice that links, that you have already visited, change color? A website could detect this colorchange.

Websites that use webservices can use the webservices' API to get the users e-mail. If a website comunicates with other websites, it could ask those websites for the e-mail.